# Inverse of $f(x, y, z)=\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$

Tags: analysis, inverse-function

> $$f(x, y, z)=\left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2},\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right)$$ 
>   Show that $f$ is locally invertible at every point except the origin and find an explicit formula for the inverse.

I can show that the determinant of the derivative matrix is not $0$ when the point is not in the origin, but I am stuck on how to find an explicit formula.

I know that in this case, the derivative of the inverse is the inverse of the derivative, but how does that work in multivariable?

Comment: Are you sure? $g(t)=f(tx, ty, tz)$ is constant. It's therefore not invertible even locally.

Comment: $f$ looks like a probability vector and thus one can find the proportions between $x,y$ and $z$ (i.e., one can get $x:y:z$), but one cannot get exact values of $x,y$ and $z$.